# Pull all images from a specified directory and then display them

Tags: php

How to display the image from a specified directory? like i want to display all the png images from a directory, in my case my directory is media/images/iconized.

I tried to look around but seems none of them fits what i really needed.

But here's my try.

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo "<img src='media/images/iconized/$curimg' /><br>\n";
    }
}
```

hope someone here could help. Im open in any ideas, recommendation and suggestion, thank you.

Comment: What isn't working with your try? You need to provide more information about the issues you are having.

Comment: This code works for me.  One can only assume you had a folder path that didn't resolve correctly.  Or the folder wasn't readable by the script.

Comment: that would be more great if we try to display image with a timer functionality.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can also use `glob` for this:

```php
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: how about multiple image extension, like instead of only png's, i want to be consider the JPEG too or gif or as what i want.

Comment: you can write like this glob("{$dirname}*.png, {$dirname}*.jpeg, {$dirname}*..gif")

Comment: @MightyLucene What you are suggesting in the comment is not working. A way that woks is this: `$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE);`
From `glob` manual : GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'

Comment: multiple extensions go like this: `$images = glob($dirname."*.[JjPp][PpNn][Gg]");`  So just fill each character with its possible combinations for a quick and okay implementation

Comment: `$dirname` can also be used with wildcards: `"media/images/*/"` or even `"media/images/*/*/"`...

Comment: I suggest to add limits to the image: `echo "<img src='$image' style='max-width:100px; max-height:100px;' /> ";`

Answer (score 22):

You can display all image from a folder using simple php script. Suppose folder name “images” and put some image in this folder and then use any text editor and paste this code and run this script.
This is php code

```
    <?php
     $files = glob("images/*.*");
     for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
      {
        $image = $files[$i];
        $supported_file = array(
                'gif',
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png'
         );

         $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
         if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
            echo basename($image)."<br />"; // show only image name if you want to show full path then use this code // echo $image."<br />";
             echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
            } else {
                continue;
            }
          }
       ?>
```

if you do not check image type then use this code

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo basename($image) . "<br />"; // show only image name if you want to show full path then use this code // echo $image."<br />";
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" />' . "<br /><br />";

}
?>
```

Comment: I believe this code assumes that every file in images folder is actually an image. If a text file is there by a mistake then it would get displayed as well.

Comment: Why start at 1 in the for loop? isn't the first file being forgotten then?

Comment: i just use a loop so i can start from 0 or 1 and i also use count(array) so loop continue all image from folder

Comment: All files, not all images. if you intent to put it like this then all extensions are accepted. including .pdf, .txt etc.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the loop from `for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)` to `for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)`:

So the correct code is

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    print $image ."<br />";
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for recursive.

```
<?php

echo scanDirectoryImages("images");

/**
 * Recursively search through directory for images and display them
 * 
 * @param  array  $exts
 * @param  string $directory
 * @return string
 */
function scanDirectoryImages($directory, array $exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'))
{
    if (substr($directory, -1) == '/') {
        $directory = substr($directory, 0, -1);
    }
    $html = '';
    if (
        is_readable($directory)
        && (file_exists($directory) || is_dir($directory))
    ) {
        $directoryList = opendir($directory);
        while($file = readdir($directoryList)) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                $path = $directory . '/' . $file;
                if (is_readable($path)) {
                    if (is_dir($path)) {
                        return scanDirectoryImages($path, $exts);
                    }
                    if (
                        is_file($path)
                        && in_array(end(explode('.', end(explode('/', $path)))), $exts)
                    ) {
                        $html .= '<a href="' . $path . '"><img src="' . $path
                            . '" style="max-height:100px;max-width:100px" /></a>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($directoryList);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference.  The: && in_array(end(explode('.', end(explode('/', $path)))), $exts)   part.

Answer (score 0):

Try the SPL **DirectoryIterator** class

```
<?
foreach ((new DirectoryIterator("mydir/")) as $fileinfo) {
   // Ignore .files (.htaccess, .DS_Store, etc)
   if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
      // Check if file is a PNG
      if ($fileinfo->getExtension() == 'png') {
         echo "This is a PNG image.";
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/aadarshi/public_html/----------/upload/view.php on line 32**

and the code is:

```
<?php

echo scanDirectoryImages("uploads");

/**
* Recursively search through directory for images and display them
* 
* @param  array  $exts
* @param  string $directory
* @return string
*/
function scanDirectoryImages($directory, array $exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'))
{
if (substr($directory, -1) == '/') {
    $directory = substr($directory, 0, -1);
}
$html = '';
if (
    is_readable($directory)
    && (file_exists($directory) || is_dir($directory))
) {
    $directoryList = opendir($directory);
    while($file = readdir($directoryList)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $file;
            if (is_readable($path)) {
                if (is_dir($path)) {
                    return scanDirectoryImages($path, $exts);
                }
                if (
                    is_file($path)
                    && in_array(end(explode('.', end(explode('/', $path)))),   $exts)
                ) {
                    $html .= '<a href="' . $path . '"><img src="' . $path
                        . '" style="max-height:100px;max-width:100px" />  </a>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($directoryList);
}
return $html;
}
```

Comment: You should add some more explanation to your answer, otherwise it might get deleted. Also fix your formatting, please.

Comment: Can you please explain what you changed in code so it does not give error?

Comment: Code does not fix anything, same error message produced "Only variables should be passed by reference "