# simple PHP, echo all images from a directory within <li>...</li>

Tags: php, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to make a simple responsive gallery using bootstrap 3  and a simple php script to display all images in a specific directory I in response to another question on here.

The issue I'm having is echoing the the required `<li></li>` tags rather then `<br></br>` as demonstrated below.

---

here is how I currently display the images, within the `<li></li>`tag with a class to display the images layout/positioning, called in the `<ul></ul>` tag.

```
<div class="container">
          <ul class="row">
            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/kitchens.jpg">
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/garden.jpg">
            </li>
            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/front.jpg">
            </li>
          </ul>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

this is the PHP im using in response to question i found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255786/3599850

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    print $image ."<br />";
    echo             

    '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
}

?>
```

---

This is my attempt :(

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    print $image ."<br />";
    echo

    '<li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
    <img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" /></li>'."<li /><li />";
}

?>
```

Comment: well, why are you echoing out **THREE** `</li>` tags for every **SINGLE** `<li>` you open? E.g. you're opening a door once, then slamming it shut three times.

Comment: @MarcB description of programming OCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many closing `</li>` tags :

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo '<li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img  class="img-responsive" src="'.$image .'" /></li>';
}

?>
```

And you don't need the `print $image ."<br />";`