# blueimp jquery file upload and read it

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm starting to use **Jquery-File-Upload** of blueimp with PHP.

After that I upload file and save in a folder, I need to read it.

Before to start to use it, I read file with `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].` How can I do it now with this plugin?

Comment: Eleborate on your question, show your code and learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't think that plugin is intended to read files from the server. You'd have to write some PHP for that. See [Pull all images from a specified directory and then display them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903289/pull-all-images-from-a-specified-directory-and-then-display-them).