# How to show all images in a folder?

Tags: php, html, png

I'm trying to make a page where I can share pictures. For the time being, I'm not using a database, just uploading them into my htdocs. All of my pictures will be PNG, and saved in a folder called `myimages`. I want a page to list all of these images, if it's possible.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This question has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17576567/12232340

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull all images from a specified directory and then display them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903289/pull-all-images-from-a-specified-directory-and-then-display-them)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all files in a directory, you can use `scandir`:

```
$dir = '/your/folder';
$files1 = scandir($dir); //returns an array of file names (strings)
```

However, if you need to restrict your search to only PNG files, use `glob` instead:

```
glob('/your/folder/*.png');
```

The pattern `*.png` matches against all file names that end with ".png", and adding the path before that ensures we only get results from inside the specified folder.