# How to load images from folder by modification date or creation date?

Tags: php, image

I use this code to load images from folder:

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Source: [Pull all images from a specified directory and then display them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903289/pull-all-images-from-a-specified-directory-and-then-display-them)

Works perfect. But load images in alphabetic order (A-Z).
My question is:

**How to load images from folder by modification date or creation date?** To get newest first.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/125047/4173464

```
<?php

$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
usort( $images, function( $a, $b ) { return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b); } );

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}

?>
```